# Angular uncaught reference $injector

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular and am having trouble set my project up. I have tried everything I have seen on google and stackoverflow(please do not send link to similar question).. None have worked. Im using angular 1.5.5 and refer to the cdn. here is what my code looks like. Thanks!

```
<html ng-app="boatup">
<link href="css/one-page-wonder.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
</body>

//in app.js
var app = angular.module('boatup', [
'boatup.controllers',
'ngRoute'
]);

//in controllers.js
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {  
 console.log("hello");
});
```

The error is angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]  in angular.js 38

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: did you include all js files?

Comment: yes, i also just included them in this post

Comment: oh silly me. Fixed it. Thanks SSH

Comment: `boatup.controllers` - do you have this module defined?

Answer (score 1):

`Uncaught reference error` in angular is caused when you are either using a module with no definition or the file with the module definition is not loaded in scripts. You have not declared the `boatup.controllers` module but added it as a dependency to your main module. Either declare and define `boatup.controllers` or remove it as a dependency as below:

```
angular.module('boatup', [
  'ngRoute'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this with your code.

```
//in app.js
 angular.module('boatup', [
'ngRoute'
 ]);

//in controllers.js
angular.module('boatup')
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {  
console.log("hello");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see from your description, you've started your project with creating different files with your application's modules. That's a good descision. But!

1. You instantiated your main app's module and assigned it to global variable `app`. It's not that big deal, but better avoid creating unnecessary variable in global scope. And if you devine gloabl variable `app` in different files, it will be owerwritten with the last file loaded.
2. You must load your module with controllers before main module. Otherwise you'll get [$injector:modulerr].

So in your case the following solution will work.

controllers.js

```
angular.module('boatup.controllers', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    console.log('hello');
  }])
```

app.js

```
angular.module('boatup', ['ngRoute', 'boatup.controllers']);
```

And you need to load in appropriate order.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="controllers.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```